# Next.js caching despite no-cache header

Tags: node.js, http, caching, next.js

I'm currently developing a solution in Next.js v13.4.12. It calls to our Express API located on a separate server. The server responds with JSON with a no-cache header.

```
X-Powered-By: Express 
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate 
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
Content-Length: 194 
ETag: W/"***" 
Date: Mon, 21 Aug 2023 14:18:40 GMT 
Connection: keep-alive 
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
```

Yet the Next.js server is still caching the response with (Cache: MISS) on the first request and (Cache: HIT) on the second.

Next.js function:

```
async function getContent(userToken: string) {
    const authToken = await getAuthToken();
    console.log(authToken);
    // const baseApi = process.env.API_BASE_URL;
    const url = baseApi + '/content';
    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            userToken: userToken,
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + authToken,
        },
        next: {
            tags: ['content']
        }
    };
    const res = await fetch(url, options)
    console.group("Content Fetch");
    const body = await res.json();
    console.log(body);
    console.groupEnd();
    return body;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because with the [`app`](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) router and on production, regardless of what the server from which you fetch says, Next.js by default caches all fetched data in API Routes and Server Components.

Since you are using [`fetch()`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/fetch), you can change this behavior with the `cache` option (set to `force-cache` by default):

```js
fetch(url, { ...options, cache: 'no-store' });
```

If you were not using `fetch()`, you would have to use [Route Segment Config](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#fetching-data-on-the-server-with-third-party-libraries).